# wrapping goto labels in parenthesis

Tags: c, goto

so i have a marco function like so:

```
#define PROPOGATE_METHOD(status, function, propogationMethod) \
     status = function; \
     if(status != eSuccess)\
     {\
        propogationMethod; \
     }
```

So like any good developer would do, I want to wrap each of the parameters as such :

```
#define PROPOGATE_METHOD(status, function, propogationMethod) \
     (status) = (function); \
     if((status) != eSuccess)\
     {\
        (propogationMethod); \
     }
```

But if I call this macro function with a goto or return, I get an error (expecting expression before goto).
`i.e. PROPOGATE_METHOD(status, functionCall(), goto Error;);`

Thoughts on working around this? I was thinking of moving the goto into the macro function, and wrapping around the label, but that throws another error :
`expected identifier or ‘*’ before ‘(’ token`

Comment: That macro showcases one of the dangers of macros. Try using it with something like `if (condition) PROPAGATE_METHOD(...)` and see your code fail miserably.

Comment: `macro` and `evil` are closely related. A `goto` is a jump to a relative address (a near jump). How would you ensure the jump address would make sense from a macro?

Comment: Show us how you use it in a minimal main function. TBH, I think what any good developer would do is to not use such a macro at all.

Comment: I don't see why this question get downvoted. I consider those macros a bad idea, but I do think it's a good question.

Comment: *"So like any good developer would do, I want to wrap each of the parameters"* - A good developer understands why the suggestion exists, what problem it solves, and most importantly, when it's not applicable. Blindly doing something is not good development.

Comment: @klutt XY problem.

Comment: The easiest solution is to not wrap `propogationMethod` in parentheses. It is already wrapped (along with the terminating semi-colon) in curly braces anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> So like any good developer would do, I want to wrap each of the parameters as such

@StoryTeller had a good response to this in comment section. *" A good developer understands why the suggestion exists, what problem it solves, and most importantly, when it's not applicable. Blindly doing something is not good development."*.

Another good applicable quote is *"Blindly following best practices is not best practice"*.

Here, it really seems like you're adding parenthesis because someone said "it's a good thing to put parenthesis around the arguments". Not because of any valid purpose in this particular case.

#### Skip the macro

I don't really see the purpose with this macro. TBH, it looks like you're showing off, but macros like this are very likely to cause hard traced bugs. If it's just to save some lines, you can actually make a somewhat decent oneliner of this without any macro.

```
if((status = foo()) != eSuccess) goto Error;
```

or

```
if((status = foo()) != eSuccess) return x;
```

or

```
if((status = foo()) != eSuccess) bar();
```

In many cases, I'd prefer making those on two or three lines. But the above is not so bad. And I would definitely say that it's better than the macro. Just remember the extra parenthesis around `status = foo()`. If forgetting this is a big concern, you could do something like this:

```
int foo_wrapper(int *status) { return *status = foo(); }
...
if(foo_wrapper(&status) != eSuccess) goto Error;
```

or even:

```
int status_assign(int *dest, int src) { return *dest = src; }
...
if(status_assign(&status, foo()) != eSuccess) goto Error;
```

On the other hand, it shouldn't be a problem, because if you compile with `-Wall`, **which you should**, you will get this:

```
warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

Personally, I don't think it's extremely important with braces when it's single statements, but if you want a oneliner with braces, well just do:

```
if((status = foo()) != eSuccess) { goto Error; }
```

Some will like it. Some will not, but it's not the most important question in the world. But I would prefer **any** of the above before the macro you're suggesting.

Compare these:

```
PROPOGATE_METHOD(status, foo(), goto Error;);
if((status = foo()) != eSuccess) goto Error;
```

When compared side by side, I cannot really see that the macro accomplishes anything at all. It doesn't make anything clearer or safer. Without the macro, I can see EXACTLY what's happening and I don't need to wonder about that. Macros have their uses, but as far as I can see here, this is not one of them.

#### From comments below

> I understand. i'm going through and refactor a code base. i prefer not to littler the code base with these if statements and prefer the macro statement because

I can understand that, but I would really encourage you to reconsider. At least if you're allowed to do it. If I were to refactor that code base, getting rid of that macro would have pretty high priority. After all, what refactoring is, is to rewrite code so it becomes better with focus on design and readability. If you don't want to do it, put parenthesis around `status` and `function` and then leave it. It will not make it good, but it will not cause any harm either.

I would not use this expression if it were you who had written that macro, but since it's not you, I can use it. "Fixing" that macro is really polishing a turd. No matter what you do, it will never shine, and it will always be a turd.

Comment: I understand. i'm going through and refactor a code base. i prefer not to littler the code base with these if statements and prefer the macro statement because

Comment: @GeorgeWu If I were to refactor a code base, getting rid of that macro would have high priority. ;)

Comment: @GeorgeWu But if you don't dare to touch it, put parenthesis around `status` and `function` and call it a day. It's not good but it's better than before, but trying to fix this macro is really like polishing a turd. It will not shine, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding if that macro is useful or confusing, and the merits of goto, consider what the parens inside a macro/define are for. If you have say, this:

```
#define FOO a + b
...
int y = x * FOO;
```

what you end up with, is `y = x * a + b` (because it's just text replacement, not a real variable), which is the same as `y = (x * a) + b`. Hence, putting parens around `(a + b)` in `FOO` fixes that.

This, of course has a similar problem (both inside `x` and outside the macro), with a similar solution:

```
#define FOO2(x) x * 123
...
int y = FOO2(a + b);
```

Now, you have

```
#define BAR(x) { x };
```

is there a similar problem there? What should `x` include that the parenthesis would remove a similar problem stemming from operator precedence? I don't really see such an issue, in a way, the braces already work to protect the `x` part from the code surrounding the macro. Adding the parens has just the effect of forcing `x` to be an expression, instead of a full statement.

Comment: The parenthesis around `status` is also pretty useless, right?

Comment: @klutt It does make sense to have `()` around status. There are a whole bunch of operators with lower precedence than  `==`/`!=`.

Comment: @PSkocik Sure, if you're doing something monumentally stupid like giving `x, y` as argument for `status`, then it would make a difference. But during somewhat normal use?

Comment: `x && y` might be a better example given that you can't use `x, y` as a single macro argument. I'd parenthesize it because there's no reason not to. But then, I wouldn't use OP's macro in the first place :D.

Comment: @PSkocik True, it does not cause any harm. But am I right that parenthesizing `status` only protects you if you're doing something really stupid, and that it's not comparable to the protection you get from parenthesizing `function`?

Comment: @klutt, I think the parens on `(status) != eSuccess` are ok, and should be there, even. Something like `x && y`, or `x = foo()` are valid expressions, and work in function calls, which macros look a lot like. So better make it work here, too. If the user wants to do something ugly, it doesn't really turn any better if they have to then spend three hours figuring out why it bursts into flames here, but not in another place.

Comment: The parens around `(status) = function` are a bit different, since `x = foo()` doesn't even make sense in place of `status` here. But I guess it would turn `x && y` into an error, instead of just something odd again, so yeah, why not do it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `status` is used twice. I ONLY meant. `(status) = function`

Comment: @klutt, Right, and `x && y = 0` is an error anyway, because it's `(x && y) = 0`, so yeah, you're right, the parens don't look that useful.

Answer (score 1):

The goto statement (`goto label;`) isn't an expression, so you cannot parenthesize it (and neither is `goto label` without the `;`, which isn't even a separately recognizable construct in C's syntax).

And even if you passed something that you can parenthesize (e.g., `longjmp(jbuf,1)`), there isn't much of a point in parenthesizing it in this context (`{ HOOK; }`).

Now if you expanded it in a context like `HOOK_EXPR * 2`, then parentheses would be useful to force `HOOK_EXPR` to group tighter than `*` (imagine you passed `3+4` as `HOOK_EXPR`), but in this context you don't need them.